# Trying to configure ArrestDB. Something I think is wrong with my Data Source Name

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to configure ArrestDB to create an api for my site.
https://github.com/alixaxel/ArrestDB

As it says in the installation I need to change the $dsn to: 
MySQL:

```
$dsn = 'mysql://[user[:pass]@]host[:port]/db/;
```

Currently I have

```
$dsn = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/database/';
```

I tried it with the brackets above, but that lead to a 503 service unavailable error.  When I remove the brackets, it leads to this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "status": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?  Everything looks correct to me

Edit:

Tried advice below and the api returned:

```
array(28) {        
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=> string(3) "200" 
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(16) "api.shopsavr.com" 
  ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" 
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" 
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36" 
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch" 
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8" 
  ["PATH"]=> string(209) "/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/sbin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin" 
  ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(136) "Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.4.20" 
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(16) "api.shopsavr.com" 
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(11) "50.28.7.250" 
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" 
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(12) "67.247.5.220" 
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(30) "/home/shopsavr/public_html/api" 
  ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(26) "webmaster@api.shopsavr.com" 
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(40) "/home/shopsavr/public_html/api/index.php" 
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "58487" 
  ["REDIRECT_URL"]=> string(8) "/PRODUCT" 
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" 
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" 
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" 
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(8) "/PRODUCT" 
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(10) "/index.php" 
  ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(10) "/index.php" 
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=> float(1383666718.92) 
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1383666718)
```

}

Comment: Case sensitive dsn protocol name perhaps? `MySQL` != `mysql`.

Comment: I tried $dsn = 'MySQL://user:password@localhost/database/'; and nothing changed.  Is that what you wanted me to try?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted you to try. It was unlikely to be that but just to check to be sure.

Comment: Studying the code it looks like it's outputting `400 Bad Request` after exhausting all other possible scenarios and not finding a match.

Comment: As if no method was requested through any of the possible paramaters. What REST request+parameters are you using?

Comment: What is the URL you are `GET`-ing?

Comment: Well according to the readme, i should be able to get certain tables, by going to: http://api.domain.com/product.  Product being a table in the database I am accessing.  I am still getting the 400 bad request from this

Comment: Use `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER)` and publish them here (replace the actual IPs and domain names with example data).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: Edit the file provided by ArrestDB, and add a line in it on the first line containing `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER);` and after it perhaps a line with `exit;`.

Comment: Did you visit the address using the "/products" URL? Right now it looks like the your "REQUEST_URI" is "/" which means you didn't have the table parameter in the URL. Otherwise it looks OK

Comment: Yes, I tried several different tables that are in the database and none of them worked

Comment: I meant 'did you visit "/products" when you had the var_dump+exit? was the output generated by var_dump obtained when visiting /products'.

Comment: I ask this because it looks like the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is "/". Which means ArrestDB doesn't receive the table bane you're trying to ask it to list. If the problem would be on the SQL connection the response code would be 503 or something around 500. But your error is 400 (not 404, or other 400 erorrs, it's actually 400).

Comment: I see.  So the problem is in how its interacting with my request, not with anything else.  Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

```
http://localhost/ArrestDB/index.php/[table]
```

worked perfect for me

don't put bracket on dns
...still working out how to post....

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

According to your code and dump information ArrestDB is not receiving your full request. The contents of your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `"/"` which means that something is likely wrong in your `.htaccess` files which should be capturing any address and directing it to the ArrestDB PHP file.

### Background info

Normally HTTP response codes in the`4XX` range represent bad requests.
Normally HTTP response codes in the`5XX` range represent errors.

ArrestDB would respond with a `4XX` error code (not 400 precisely but another 4XX error) if  some other error would occur (bad SQL parameters, server timeout etc.).
ArrestDB would respond with a `5XX` error code (503 in particular) if the database connection would be in any way "bad".

### Reasoning

Because of the fact that it responds with precisely 400 as the error code it means that there is no "specific" error code it can supply (400 meaning "unknown type of bad connection").

### Possible fix

First to confirm my theory I recommend you remove the `var_dump + exit` I asked you to put in and in stead write `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/products";`. This should force ArrestDB to think it needs to list the `products` table. After confirming everything works when we use this hack we'll attempt to fix your `.htaccess` problem.

Comment: Where did you enter the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/products";` line? at the beginning of the file I hope.

Comment: Yes I replaced the var_dump + exit from earlier with it.

Comment: Any idea why your ArrestDB is outputting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/products";`? That line should't be outputted, it should be executed. It wouldn't be outputted unless you wrote it before the `<?php` tag.

Comment: Do you have xdebug on your hosting? Can you activate it so we can debug remotely?

Comment: That was the last place I stopped with it.  I tried it before the PHP and then again after.  I removed it now.  It's just after the php part.  I don't think I have xdebug, let me look into it

Comment: OK it should be activated

Comment: Please set `php_flag xdebug.remote_enable On`, `php_flag xdebug.remote_connect_back On`, `php_value xdebug.idekey PHPSTORM_XDEBUG`, in an `.htaccess` file within the folder where the api resides.

Comment: OK an .htaccess file has been created within that folder with just those three lines

Comment: Sorry but where I am right now I can't route the XDebug data. When I get home I can take a look (in a few hours).

Comment: Did you by any chance notice some xdebug settings in your hosting? It might have a fixed IP that it's allowing to use xdebug (which is not mine).

Comment: I did not see any settings in cpanel or anywhere else.  I contacted support and had them install it on the server

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the .htaccess file you need to put the full URL to work, just like this: `http://localhost/ArrestDB/index.php/[table]`